# Does enabling LPIM work even if the memory pressure is coming from SQL Server itself

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory, performance, plan-cache, performance-tuning

I have a scenario where I have 128 GB Physical memory for the SQL Server 2016 machine.
It is a SQL Server dedicated machine.
I have `110 GB` allocated to SQL Server itself.

I have performance issues when the CPU usage is high or the no of connections go high. It is normal for the CPU usage to go high as there are more request coming in with more connections.
I looked at the RING BUFFERS,plan cache etc. I see that plan cache gets cleared often when i have more usage. Also RING BUFFER indicated memory pressure. I see that for most of the cases `IndicatorProcess=2` which means SQL server internally detected memory pressure. On few occasions it is `IndicatorSystem = 2`.

I have been struggling with this for sometime now. I have tuned the frequently executed queries and most of them runs fast when there are plans available in plan cache.
My Question here is :

1. Does enabling LPIM help in this scenario since i see 
   `IndicatorProcess=2` in most of the cases.
2. I already have 128GB RAM.Is that the maximum i can have for SQL Server 2016 Standard.?

**Additional Info**

[image]

Here is what the monitoring tool has to say for the last one hour.

[image]

Comment: Can you add output of `select @@version` in the question. Also add the output of  `select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory`

Comment: @Shanky Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 2):

> Does enabling LPIM help in this scenario since i see IndicatorProcess=2 in most of the cases.

No.

> I already have 128GB RAM.Is that the maximum i can have for SQL Server 2016 Standard.?

Yes.

And

> I see that plan cache gets cleared often when i have more usage
>   and
>   most of [the frequent queries] runs fast when there are plans available in plan cache

Suggests you should focus on your plan cache.  Are there a large number of single-use plans?  If so consider setting the [optimize for ad hoc workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) configuration option.

Comment: There are single-use plans but there are plans with high execution count as well.optimize for ad hoc workload is set to true already.Forced parametrization is also enabled.